# Bind the same "texture memory" to textures with different dimensionalities

Tags: opengl, textures

How can I bind the same "texture memory" to textures with different dimensionalities.

For example, I need to access an array of 2D images using a `sampler2DArray` in a shader, and a `sampler3D` in another shader, without having to load and store the data on the graphics card memory twice.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, tex);
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, ...);    // allocate & store pixel data
```

and then:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, tex);    // "reuse" the texture storage with a
                                      // different dimensionality in another 
                                      // texture unit
```

But the last line is obviously invalid.

Is there any method to do something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL (4.3+) has a concept called [view textures](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/View_Texture). If you create a texture with [immutable storage](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Immutable_Storage_Texture), then you can create a texture that references that immutable storage. Or part of that immutable storage. You can change things like image formats (if they're compatible) and even texture targets. You can extract a single element of a 2D array and use it as a regular 2D texture. Or you can turn a 2D texture into a 2D array of 1 layer.

However, you cannot view a 2D array texture's storage as a 3D texture. Or vice-versa. Their mipmaps don't work the same way. In a 3D texture, mipmaps decrease in X, Y and Z. In 2D array textures, they only get smaller in X and Y.

Even *Vulkan* doesn't let you create a `VkImageView` that is a 3D image view from a `VkImage` that was allocated as an arrayed 2D image (or vice-versa).